# Why does `Future#toString` returns `"List()"`?

Tags: scala, future

Calling `.toString` on a future without waiting for complession leads to nondeterministic results. My question is *why* calling `.toString` on uncompleted futures returns `"List()"` in scala 2.10.x and 2.11.x? [The implementation](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.8/src/library/scala/concurrent/impl/Promise.scala) does not seem to be explicit about that.

This behavior can be observed from the REPL:

```
scala> import scala.concurrent.Future, scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

scala> Future(1).toString
res0: scala.concurrent.Future[Int] = Success(1)

scala> Future(1).toString
res1: scala.concurrent.Future[Int] = List()
```

Note that Scala 2.12.x will likely explicitly implement `Future#toString` to return `"Future(<not completed>)"` instead ([source](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.0-M5/src/library/scala/concurrent/impl/Promise.scala#L48)).

---

Edit: evidence that this is not an artefact comming from the REPL or "some hidden implicit" (`-Yno-predef` removes all the default implicits):

**Future.scala:**

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

object Main extends App {
  System.out.println(Future(1).toString)
}
```

**build.sbt:**

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

scalacOptions := Seq(
  "-deprecation",
  "-encoding", "UTF-8",
  "-feature",
  "-unchecked",
  "-Yno-predef",
  "-Xfatal-warnings",
  "-Xlint",
  "-Yinline-warnings",
  "-Yno-adapted-args",
  "-Ywarn-dead-code",
  "-Ywarn-unused-import",
  "-Ywarn-numeric-widen",
  "-Ywarn-value-discard",
  "-Xfuture")
```

Comment: I'm consistently getting `scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@34a2d6e0` with Scala 2.11.7

Comment: In 2.11.8 you do get `List()` for an uncompleted `Future`.

Comment: you're most likely have some hidden implicit defined that generate such behaviour.

Comment: That's an in the debug of REPL. Try to assign it to a `val`

Comment: @cchantep I don't think it is, `println(Future(1).toString)` also prints `List()`, same results can also be reproduced out of the REPL.

Comment: Have you tried to assign as suggested ?

Comment: @rumoku it's not, see my edit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It was an unfortunate side effect of removing the dependence of `sun.misc.Unsafe`. It is corrected in Scala 2.12 and newer versions of Scala 2.11 IIRC.

Comment: Confirming the fix is on 2.11.9 forthcoming.

Comment: Out of curiosity, could you explain how `sun.misc.Unsafe` relates to `"List()"` here?

Comment: We replaced it by extending AtomicReference, which sadly silently "overrode" toString. The List being printed is the list of callbacks.