# Scala return List() from function instead of Future[custom object]

Tags: scala

I have below code which method returns Future[Account] where Account is the case class object. Below is the code

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
case class Account (acctId:String, userId:String)
object NewTest extends App{

val account = getAcct
println ("account Fut is " +account)

def getAcct(): Future[Account] = {

 val accountFutOpt = Future {
   //Some(Account("1234","5678"))
   None
 }

(for {
  accountOpt <- accountFutOpt
  account = accountOpt
  if account.isDefined
 }yield account.get).recoverWith {
   case _: NoSuchElementException =>
    //println(s"No Account associated to acctId ")
    Future.failed(new IllegalStateException(s"No account associated to acctId  "))
  }
 }
}
```

When the accountFutOpt is Some(account) the result is Success(Account) as expected. But when the accountFutOpt is None, the output of the method is List as below.

```
account Fut is List()
```

List() instead of Future should throw compilation error correct?

Comment: That's not the output I'm getting.

Comment: what is your scala version. mine is scalaVersion := "2.11.8" . Also, what is the output you are getting.

Comment: That's just some internals leaking out of the `toString` method in some Scala version. I think it says `List()` when the `Future` is not completed yet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does \`Future#toString\` returns \`"List()"\`?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38478466/why-does-futuretostring-returns-list)

Comment: My IDE is running 2.11.7.  The output I see is `...Promise$DefaultPromise@...`.  When I unpack the `Future` via `account.value` I see the expected results of `Some(...)` and `None`.  I suspect that @Jasper-M is correct and you're seeing a `toString` anomaly.